# Understanding super() and questions about class constructors

Tags: python, class, super

The following is a sample piece of code from a program that I'm referring to. I realized that I hadn't truly this concept, so I'm asking here.

```
class Chef(games.Sprite):
    """
    A chef which moves left and right, dropping pizzas.
    """
    image = games.load_image("chef.bmp")

    def __init__(self, y = 0, speed = 2, odds_change = 200):
        """ Initialize the Chef object. """
        super(Chef, self).__init__(image = Chef.image,
                                   x = games.screen.width / 2,
                                   y = 55,
                                   dx = speed)

        self.odds_change = odds_change
        self.time_til_drop = 0
```

This is what I thought is the case:

the sixth line `def __init__(self, y = 0, speed = 2, odds_change = 200)` gives the object its initial values and the values enclosed in the kernel:

`super(Chef, self).__init__(image = Chef.image, x = games.screen.width / 2,                                     y = 55,dx = speed)` deal with these values of the object *after* initialization. Making the sixth line values fairly arbitary. For example I was able to change the value of y in the sixth line constructor to any arbitary number, and the object stayed in the same y coordinate on the screen. Is my understanding of this correct?

Comment: One niggle: `__init__` isn't the constructor, that's `__new__` (which you rarely need to override).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `super` actually does is calls the parent class' corresponding method. http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super
So, in your case, you are calling the `__init__` method of the class `games.Sprite` from your defined class `Chef`

The reason you got the object at the same position although you changed y in the sixth line because you didn't change the parameter `y=55` which you are passing to the `super` function. If you will change this y to something else, your object will definitely move.

The general practice while using `super` is to pass the same parameters as you get from the `__init__` method. In your code, you are not passing any of the parameters of `__init__` to `super(Chef, self).__init__` and hence the parameters defined in `__init__` are more or less meaningless. So your code should be some what like this -

```
class Chef(games.Sprite):
    """
    A chef which moves left and right, dropping pizzas.
    """
    image = games.load_image("chef.bmp")

    def __init__(self, x = games.screen.width / 2, y = 55, speed = 2, odds_change = 200):
        """ Initialize the Chef object. """
        super(Chef, self).__init__(image = Chef.image,
                               x = x,
                               y = y,
                               dx = speed)     # although this will work, you should either rename dx as speed or vice-versa

        self.odds_change = odds_change
        self.time_til_drop = 0
```

Rem, you can take more parameters in the `__init__` method then you pass to `super(Chef, self).__init__` function.

Comment: Great answer, one more thing that is probably a daft question: is the parent class games.Sprite or Chef? And also when in the first init (the sixth line), the parameters are just initial conditions. Am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: And by initial conditions I mean default arguments... I'm still trying to gauge what exactly using init is doing each time we use it. Once as is, and the second time in the super. The super() is clearer because of your explanation, but what of the other?

Comment: Parent class is the one from which you are inheriting your class. So the parent class for your class `Chef` is `games.SPRITE`. The parameters in `__init__` are just default parameters only if they have a default value. If they don't have a default value they are required parameters.

Comment: `__init__` gets called immediately after an object of the class `Chef` is made where `self` contains the reference to this object created. So , if there are any required parameters in `__init__` then they are required to be passed while making a new object of the class. 
Perhaps, this might help-  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/Class/Inheritedmethod.htm  
(it has not an example of super.)

Answer (score 3):

Naw. The `= 0`, `= 2`, etc., don't initialize the object - they're just default arguments to a function. Eg:

```
def foo(x, y=20):
    print x, y
foo(10, 30)
foo(10)
```

In the code you wrote, that means you can just call `Chef()`, and in the constructor, the values for the variables `y`, `speed`, and `odds_change` will be the default values.

This doesn't set the instance variables, though. The code that sets them is in `games.Sprite`'s constructor (the superclass of `Chef`).

Comment: But then changing the sixth line to (self, y, speed = 2...) executes to an error as well! Could you explain?

Comment: @Louis93: how are you calling `Chef`? if you call it like `Chef()`, and the `__init__` is declared as `(self, y, speed=2,...)`, then you'll get an error since you have to provide a value for `y`.